# Is my server lacking storage space?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Looking for some help here.

I have two ASP.Net web applications using SQL Server 2005 hosted on a dedicated  Windows 2003 server. One of the applications only receives around 100 unique hits a day, however, the other receives on average 6,000 unique hits a day. Both applications have been live for around 4 years now without any problems.

Recently I have noticed both applications slowing down quite a bit, page loads taking a long time, much longer than usual. I have also noticed one of the applications getting the following error maybe once or twice a day

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)

The capacity of the two databases together comes to around 3 Gig, and the C Drive on the Server is around 20 Gig. However, the current free space on the C Drive is sitting at 3 Gig.

I thought originally the timeout error was coming from leaking connections in my code, but now I am not so sure because as stated, the applications have been live for 4 years now without any trouble like this.

Do you think the issue could be my server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you have 3GB free, then the problem is not caused by being low in disk space.

However, if you've never done routine DB maintenance in over 4 years, that could certainly explain it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I don't come from a database background, could you suggest what maintenance tasks I could carry out on my database. I recently added extra indexes to my tables, but this did not help much.

Comment: No, I can't. It depends on what your database is doing, usage, etc. Google "SQL Server Maintenance Best Practices" and start reading.